# SQL query to Delete products with specific attribute Woocommerce

Tags: sql, wordpress, woocommerce

I need SQL query to delete products with specific attribute in Woocommerce Wordpress. For example i have 2000 products with attribute ID - "Season" and its data "Summer". I wan to run SQL so it delete all products with "Season" attribute = "Summer" .

Can anyone help? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

We can use a subquery here to identify products having the attribute/data pair you want to delete:

```
DELETE
FROM yourTable
WHERE productId IN (
    SELECT productId
    FROM
    (
        SELECT productId
        FROM yourTable
        WHERE attributeID = 'Season' AND data = 'Summer'
    ) x
);
```

Comment: This the third (fourth?) anonymous downvote I have received today, with zero feedback, and not all of my answers deserved to be downvoted.  Is there any feedback here possible?

Comment: Yo no comprendo.